# windows command prompt nodejs `npm i` unknown error

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, command-prompt, pm2

Hello I am trying to run a nodejs program on windows 10 that uses puppeteer to launch a  browser and do stuff. I've decided to try and get it working with command prompt instead of the ubuntu subsystem.

I have nodejs, npm, and nvm-windows installed and usable in my command prompt:

```
C:\Users\marti\Documents\projectFolder\>npm -v
5.6.0

C:\Users\marti\Documents\projectFolder>node -v
v8.10.0
```

When I run `npm i` inside my project, it installs most of the dependencies but results in this error:

```
C:\Users\marti\Documents\projectFolder>npm i
npm ERR! path C:\Users\marti\Documents\Bungee\crawler\Crawler-workers\node_modules\.bin\shjs
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, lstat 'C:\Users\marti\Documents\Bungee\crawler\Crawler-workers\node_modules\.bin\shjs'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\marti\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-27T19_22_46_131Z-debug.log
```

an errno -4094, something to do with lsat maybe? I need `pm2` for a project, and installing it with `npm i pm2` results in the same error. I am running command prompt as an administrator, does anyone have advice for solving this issue? Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running it under node 10 or node 12?

Comment: changed my node to use version 12.17.0 and npm uses 6.14.4, ran npm i and got the same error output

Comment: Did you delete node_modules in between?

Comment: The command fails at shjs, if you run `npm list shjs`, which package depends on it? Could you include your `package.json`?

Comment: fixed by deleting package-lock.json and reinstalling, should have tried that first

Answer (score 1):

fixed by deleting package-lock.json and reinstalling, should have tried that first